# Image.Save crashing: {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: encoder"}

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to save an image into a `MemoryStream` but it is failing under certain conditions.

Here is the code:

The following code succeeds:

```
Image img = Bitmap.FromStream(fileStream);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat);  // This succeeds.
```

The following code fails:

```
Image img = Bitmap.FromStream(fileStream);
Image thumb = img.GetThumbnailImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null, System.IntPtr.Zero);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
thumb.Save(ms, thumb.RawFormat);  // This fails.
```

Notice that the second snippet is using an image created using `Image.GetThumbnailImage`.

What is the difference?  Does anyone have any idea why is it failing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe the problem has to do with this part of the [`GetThumbnailImage` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx):

> If the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) contains an embedded thumbnail image, this method retrieves the embedded thumbnail and scales it to the requested size. If the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) does not contain an embedded thumbnail image, this method creates a thumbnail image by scaling the main image.

This probably accounts for the intermittent behaviour (AKA "certain conditions"). The explanation is in the following [Microsoft Connect ticket](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98452/image-save-with-imageformat-memorybmp-causes-exception):

> The underlying API is not able to locate an encoder for the MemoryBmp image type. We will need to investigate this will the GDI+ team. In the meantime, you should be able to simply change your ImageFormat to ImageFormat.Bmp rather than ImageFormat.MemoryBmp and it should work. It will still be saved to the MemoryStream using the BMP format.

In all likelihood, if there is no embedded thumbnail, the new thumbnail generated by the `GetThumbnailImage` API is in fact going to have a `RawFormat` of `MemoryBmp` which has no associated encoder - thus the specific error message you're seeing.

Just don't use `thumb.RawFormat`; since you know it's a bitmap anyway, use `ImageFormat.Bmp` instead.

*P.S. Please note that although I deleted my earlier answer because it turned out to not to be relevant to this particular issue, it is still important to use the `GetThumbnailImage` API properly as the documentation specifies; you **must** pass a valid delegate for the `callback` parameter instead of `null`, otherwise it can fail, and you still need to be wrapping disposables in `using` clauses.*

Comment: changing `thumb.Save(ms, thumb.RawFormat)` to `thumb.Save(ms, thumb.Bmp)` did it!